# Картинка из файла (c sd карты) на ImageButton

Tags: android, button

Как в Android создать ImageButton с возможность загрузки картинки из файла?

Допустим, хочу иметь на кнопке портрет Президента или чемпиона мира по фигурному катанию - чтоб не обновлять программу целиком когда он сменится, а только новый файл залить.

Comment: первый ответ в гугле. https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20image%20from%20sd%20card%20into%20imagebutton&es_th=1

Answer (score 3):

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("path/to/file");
ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
button1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```